# Insert new column with one day later in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I plan to insert a new column 'date2' where each value is one day later from a date of the same row in a column 'date1'.

From the orginal table:

```
date1        date2
2015-07-03   0000-00-00   
2016-04-30   0000-00-00   
2017-12-31   0000-00-00
```

To the extended table with the additional column 'date2':

```
date1        date2
2015-07-03   2015-07-04
2016-04-30   2016-05-01
2017-12-31   2018-01-01
```

How can I achieve the above table in MySQL?

Comment: One simple way is: `DATE_ADD(date1, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS Date2`

Comment: This solves the problem. Thank you so much @GiorgosBetsos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @GiorgosBetsos.

One way to solve the problem is to `update table set date2 = DATE_ADD(date1, INTERVAL 1 DAY)`